# Centering 3 boxes inside div

Tags: css, html

I am trying to center the blue boxes inside the grey box, but as soon as I have them centered, they are not even horizontally.  I can't figure what is causing them to be uneven.  Can anyone see what's causing it?

```
div.event_container{
width:100%;
overflow: hidden;
height:245px;
padding: 5px;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
background-color:#999;
border-top: 0px;
position:relative;
top: 65px;
left: 0px;
clip: rect(5px, 0px, 0px, 0px);
z-index: 1;
}

div.event_box{
    display: inline-block;
    width:27%;
height:190px;
    padding: 10px;
margin: 10px auto;
background-color:#B9DAF4;
    position: relative;
border-top: 0px;
    border-radius: 5px 10px 5px 10px / 10px 5px 10px 5px;
}

.event_text {
width:90%;
min-width:700px;
max-width:2000px;
min-height:100px;
    position: relative;
    top: 40px;
padding: 15px;
margin-top: 60px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
background-color:#fff;
    text-align: left;
border-top: 1px solid #A3A3A3;
    z-index:1;
}

.div_center3 {
margin:0 auto;
width:850px;
background-color: #666;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
}

#content{
    width:99%;
    max-width: 1200px;
height:100%;
    margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align:center;
background-color:222;
border-top: 0px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1px;
    padding-bottom: 130px;
}
```

---

The Code

```
<div id="content">
 <div class="div_center3">

<!--Start header text-->
       <div class="event_text">
        <p class="htext"> Information & Innovation at USM hosts a variety of     business     and industry tours through the academic year, 
            as well as showcases projects and hosting job fairs.  I&I is very active     in coordinating efforts with Maine business and industry 
            leaders in many capacities.</p>
        <p class="htext">I&I hosts tours of local IT industry leaders, such as Texas     Instruments and Wright Express in South Portland.
              In December of 2010, I&I showcased an array of research and     development     projects at the fifth Business and Industry Homecoming event 
            where technology leaders and staffing specialists from major Maine         corporations were in attendance for the corporate event at the John 
            Mitchell Center at USM Gorham's campus.</p>  

    </div><!--End event_text div-->
   <!--End Header text-->


<!--Start event boxes-->
    <div class="event_container">

 <div class="event_box">       
        <h3>State of IT in Maine Conference</h3>
            Oct 18, 2012
           <p style="text-align: justify;">Stay Tuned for more information!!</p> 
          <!--<a href="#">Read more</a>-->
       </div>

<div class="event_box">       
        <h3>Business & Industry Tours</h3>
            Fall of 2012
           <p style="text-align: justify;">Each year, company representatives conduct     business tours for IT students where they describe their
            particular industry, as well as types of jobs and needed skills. This is a     great opportunity for students to network and 
            get real world knowledge of the workforce.</p>
            <p>Stay tuned for more information!! </p> 
          <!--<a href="#">Read more</a>-->
       </div>

       <div class="event_box">       
        <h3>IT Job Fair</h3>
            Fall of 2012
            <p style="text-align: justify;">This is an exclusive opportunity for IT     and Computer Science students.<br />  
                 Come meet potential employers offering internships and employment in     Information Technology and Computer Science feilds.
            </p>
            <p style="text-align: justify;">Stay Tuned for more information!!</p> 
            <!--<a href="#">Read more</a>-->

       </div>
   </div>

   <div id="pipe_container">
       <div id="event_pipe">     
           <script src="http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/pps/listbadge_1.6.js">         {"pipe_id":"2a44070dcf6974aea04ad155a76caef4","_btype":"list","width":"80%","height":"350px    ", "margin":"auto"}</script>
       </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   </div>
 <!--end holder-->
```

Comment: POst your HTML code formatted or on a pastebin please

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the vertical alignment; add`verical-align:top` to `div.event_box`

By default elements have a vertical-align of baseline which aligns the baseline of the element with the baseline of the parent element.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/74P3T/)